# How to parse csv file and do arithmetic operations on it using c++?

Tags: c++, csv

This is my [CSV file](https://ethercalc.org/fo128cmznr) and I want to parse this csv data and fetch corresponding columns. Then use fetched columns to carry out some arithmetic operations. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
//https://ethercalc.org/fo128cmznr

int main()
{
    std::vector <double> vec,vec1;
    std::ifstream theFile("stock.csv");
    std::string symbol,date;
    std::string line;
    double open,high,low,close,adjclose,volume;
    while (getline(theFile, line))
    {
        std::stringstream linestream(line);
        std::getline(linestream, symbol, ',');
        std::getline(linestream, date, ',');
        std::getline(linestream, open, ',');
        std::getline(linestream, high, ',');
        std::getline(linestream, low, ',');
        std::getline(linestream, close, ',');
        std::getline(linestream, adjclose, ',');
        std::getline(linestream, volume, '\n');
        std::cout<<"volume "<<volume<<"\n";
        double sum=(volume+close)/open;
        double rat=(open/high);
        std::cout<<"sum "<<sum<<"\n";
        vec.push_back(sum);
        vec1.push_back(rat);

    }
return 0;
}
```

Here is the problem; I can parse the data if I converted every variable into a string but then i cant perform arithmetic operations in string form. But if I used other format of variable such as double,float etc then I cant parse the csv file itself. How to solve this problem?

Comment: stof(), stod() etc.

Answer (score 0):

You demonstrated that you know what `std::stringstream` is, and you know how to use it.

So, take the `low`, for example. Take this `std::string`, use it to construct a `std::stringstream`, then use `operator>>` to put it into a `double`, or a `float`.

Comment: Why not use `std::stod` and family?